# When building blitjs project I get the following error: "Type error: ',' expected on ...'"

Tags: typescript, blitz.js

I'm using the Blitjs framework. I have installed a custom package I have created ([@devqaly/browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@devqaly/browser))

When building the project (`blitz build`) I get the following error:

```
$ blitz build
Loaded env from /Users/brunofrancisco/xxxx/xxxxx/.env.production
Loaded env from /Users/brunofrancisco/xxx/xxxxx/.env.local
Loaded env from /Users/brunofrancisco/xxxxx/xxxxx/.env
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Generating route manifest
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@devqaly/browser/dist/index.d.ts:3:38
Type error: ',' expected.

  1 | import { DevqalySDK } from './sdk';
  2 | import { EventType, SDKEvent } from './services/Events';
> 3 | export { DevqalySDK, EventType, type SDKEvent };
    |                                      ^
  4 |
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Locally my package works just fine. Whenever I build my package no errors are thrown. Only when I try to build Blitzjs the error is thrown.

I have tried researching what this errors means but only found reasons to other frameworks that are not related to Blitjs. Any clue on how I can solve this? Either by editing my package or by changing some configuration on Blitjs configs file

Answer (score 0):

I was using a typescript version in my blitjs project that didn't have support for the `type` keyword.

I have updated my typescript to a version that has support to it and the issue was solved.